# QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks

Tags: go

I'm trying to use wkhtmltopdf to render a PDF page from HTML. When I try to call Create, it gives me bunch of errors regarding `QSslSocket: cannot resolve`. Anyone knows what's happening here?

```golang
func main() {
  tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("docs/template.html")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  tempBuff := new(bytes.Buffer)

  err = tmpl.Execute(tempBuff, data)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  page := wkhtmltopdf.NewPageReader(tempBuff)

  pdfGen, err := wkhtmltopdf.NewPDFGenrator()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }

  pdfGen.AddPage(page)
  pdfGen.Orientation.Set(wkhtmltopdf.OrientationLandscape)
  pdfGen.Dpi.Set(300)

  // Error happens here
  err = pdfGen.Create()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
}
```

These are the errors

```bash
Loading pages (1/6)
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_num_locks                  ] 10%
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_pop_free
QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_load_error_strings
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function sk_num
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method2%
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done                                                                      
Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_locking_callback
```

Comment: What version of `wkhtmltopdf` are you using? (run `wkhtmltopdf --version`). I'd suggest testing `wkhtmltopdf` from the command line (see [docs](`https://wkhtmltopdf.org/`)) to confirm it's working because this looks like an issue with that software rather than something Go related ([This issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3001) may help).

Comment: @Brits the version is 0.12.4

Comment: @Brits i just tried running `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf` like on the docs, and the same error appears

Comment: Please try updating to .12.6 as per the issue I linked. As this occurs when run from the command line it's not `go` related.

Answer (score 2):

I was using 0.12.4 and upgraded to 0.12.6. Solved it for me!

[wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html)

[install guide on computingforgeeks.com](https://computingforgeeks.com/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/)

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it fixed the problem trying to run wkhtmltopdf on Oracle LINUX:

```
sudo -i yum install compat-openssl10.x86_64
```

Comment: This solves the problem for any Qt application having the errors with OpenSSL library. Tested on Rocky Linux

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a more recent version of wkhtmltopdf, at least 0.12.5.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are on Ubuntu, try installing it without composer.**

```
sudo apt update
```

```
sudo apt install wkhtmltopdf -y
```

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```